# Using tf.hub.KerasLayer in TF 2.12 Functional API throws ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following a youtube tutorial for text classification using tensorflow
This is my code:-

```
hub_handle = "https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(hub_handle, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
hub_layer(list(df_tf)[0][0])
```

I get the following error:-

**ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'keras_layer_8' (type KerasLayer).
Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
inputs: (
tf.Tensor(
[[b'I need assistance with setting up a trailing stop order']
[b'What is the procedure for updating my account preferences?'], shape=(32, 1), dtype=string))**

**input_signature: (
TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)).
Call arguments received by layer 'keras_layer_8' (type KerasLayer):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 1), dtype=string)
• training=None**

I am new to tensorflow, any help or a resource that would point me in the right direction will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines look good.

However in the third line, the input to the module should be a **batch of sentences in a 1-D tensor of strings**, as per the TensorFlow Hub **nnlm-en-dim50** [documentation](https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2).

Please refer to this code and your issue would be resolved :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

Download the IMDB Dataset and perform the train-test split.

```
train_data, validation_data, test_data = tfds.load(
    name="imdb_reviews", 
    split=('train[:60%]', 'train[60%:]', 'test'),
    as_supervised=True)
```

Explore the data

```
train_examples_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_data.batch(10)))
```

Check the train examples

```
train_examples_batch
```

Check the train labels

```
train_labels_batch
```

Create a Keras layer that uses a TensorFlow Hub model to embed the sentences,

```
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[], 
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
hub_layer(train_examples_batch[:3])
```

You can find the complete code as per the [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/drive/1EFxWsXolp7DDA0NNNb4I2kadO2kY-Vae#scrollTo=In2nDpTLkgKa).